# Production server url not there but development server is?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am running my app on the production server for first time. I have a url with admin logon enabled in the `app.yml`.  The script runs when I browse to its URL when running on the development server.  However, after uploading to the production server when I go to the same URL I get the following error:

> The requested URL `/tasks/` was not found on this server.

Why would this occur?  I tried updating again.

The URL and script is the third one in the my `app.yml` file:

```
##app.yml file
application: generic_app_name
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
    - url: /remote_api
      script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
      login: admin

    - url: /stats.*
      script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/appstats/ui.py

    - url: /tasks/SR2pop
      script: PopulateSR2.py
      login: admin


    - url: /
      script: dbsample.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the capitalization of your script exactly as specified in app.yaml? The production servers are case-sensitive, but if you're developing on Windows, the development server isn't. Check the capitalization of PopulateSR2.py matches the one in app.yaml.

Also, your file *is* called app.yaml, not app.yml, right?

Comment: I just solved this last night, along the same thought process, but I was entering everything exactly the same, I ended up just changing the name of the file with no numbers or capitals and now it works fine? lol

Answer (score 1):

Your 3rd handler is going to match only the exact string `/tasks/SR2pop`. None of your handlers will match `/tasks/`.

Comment: I agree.  Though I wonder if there is a typo in his question since he mentions that he is able to access the URL successfully when running on the development server.

Comment: agreed, on development server I enter localhost:8080/tasks/SR2pop and it works, on the production server i enter http://www.app_name.appspot.com/tasks/SR2pop but nothign pops up, just wondering if anyone has any thoughts this has to be something simple.